# C# MVC continue with routes after route failure

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

Is it possible to have the mvc framework to continue to the next matching route after a route fails to find a controller?

I have views in a database but I would like to have routes that match actual controllers before it looks in the database for matching views.

I have these routes atm.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}"
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Content",
            "{*route}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

If the "Default" route was to fail to find a controller/action could it continue to the next route "Content"?

Cheers,

Rick.

Comment: What did your test show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC routing works by matching the URL to a route value so as long as the pattern matches then it will try to use that route whether there is an actual controller/action pair that matches up to the URL or not.  In order to do this you could put something in your OnActionExecute that evaluates the controller action names and if it doesn't match the database then does an ignore route on the default route. I would add a different route that is the pattern you want to match and use that rather than the default route and put your default route at the bottom of the list so it can be your catchall fall thru as intended.

Comment: I've done some more with it this morning and if I have the url /test/test and there is no controller called test with an action test the route does not fall through to the next one in line which would check the database. Is there some way to modify the routing to allow this?

Comment: I did some digging around in the MVC source good to try find a way to do what I wanted but I figured it was just easier to change {controller}/{action} to a fixed controller part like Tracking/{action} and just have the database as a fall through.

Comment: Yep. You hit it on the head.   You can kind of accomplish this by working with routes outside of the Global asax.   Basically have a lookup table of sorts in your database and then in your Action method check the database for the view and if it isn't there call a route by name.   You may be able to accomplish something similar with named routes without the database check but I haven't had my morning coffee so I'm not firing on all cylinders yet :-)